# Screen resolution problem

Tags: screen, display-resolution

The display screen settings in 16.10 are stuck in very large solution. The settings template is also too large. I cannot reach to the bottom of it to click on "apply" to change the settings. I have tried to change it trough terminator but without results. 
                                     With thanks in advance,
                                                              Asgeir.

Comment: Since when you have this problem? Since fresh installation or after doing some alteration in configurations?

Comment: I was trying out some sizes of resolution. Then it stuck in largest size, could not reach down to the apply button for executing it to the default size. Have tried many suggestions from Ubuntu help, but nothing works.

Comment: didn't you forget to politely ask terminator to get back? :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `xrandr`. Called without arguments it shows connected screen(s) and the supported resolutions. For example:

```
$ xrandr

HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Changing resolutions:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1280x1024
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can reach the `Resolution` selection box. After having selected a resolution, the box has an orange border. This means you can currently interact with it using your keyboard. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> 7 times. At this point, you can interact with the `Apply` button. Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After that, the resolution changes and you can click the button `Keep this resolution` with your mouse.

Comment: Or you can press <Alt> and drag the window around with the mouse to expose the Apply button.

Answer (score 0):

quick (and dirty?)

open terminal window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
$ xrandr
```

it will show the supported screen resolutions, pick one, for example 1280x1024

```
$ xrandr -s 1280x1024
```

this will set the screen resolution
Note, this is only temporary solution for the current session.